# ASP.NET MVC Dynamic List Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, list, binding, strong-typing

I have a strongly typed mvc page which I wont to bind a unorder list to a list of objects.  So in mvc view it might look something like

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.WhatYouDoL) { %>
<li><%: Html.Encode(item.Text) %><input type="hidden" name="WhatYouDoL[0].Reference" /></li>
<% } %>
```

My view model might look something like

```
public class ViewModelQuoteWhatYouDoInMotorTrade
    {
        public List<WhatYouDo> WhatYouDoL { get; set; }
    }
```

and my list contains object like

```
public struct WhatYouDo
    {

        public decimal Percent { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

This binds ok providing I use WhatYouDoL[0].Reference with the index ([0]) which when loading I can set with an index.  The problem is I want to add and remove from this list on the client side.  So I might have some js which adds and extra list item and removes the current.  This means I have to somehow manage the indexes in the name and keep them in order and non duplicate on the client side.  Does anyone know if there is a way to get around using the index in the name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to update list using Ajax? Or what. Please provide some more info.

Answer (score 0):

There is, probably, a mistake:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.WhatYouDoL) { %>
<li><%: Html.Encode(item.Text) %><input type="hidden" name="WhatYouDoL[0].Reference" /></li>
<% } %>
```

Maybe it should be:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.WhatYouDoL) { %>
<li><%: item.Text %><input type="hidden" name="<%: item.Reference %>" /></li>
<% } %>
```

You don't need to encode as long as you use `<:` [proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676236/are-and-the-same-thing-as-embbed-code-expression-blocks)

Comment: don't forget colon in <% item.Reference %>, I think it should be <%: item.Reference %>

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer.  I might not have put my question across properly.  The problem is having to use this naming convention name="WhatYouDoL[0].Reference".  I want to add and remove to the list client side but this means i need to make sure at the end all the [0] indexes are correct in the collection.  I was hoping o could do name="WhatYouDoL.Reference" and mvc would work out it is a collection.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think this might work.  I havent tried it yet though.  Non sequential indexes part. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: I think this might work. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx