# What is the difference between <%: item["Title"] %> and <%= item["Title"] %>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are <%: and <%= the same thing as embbed code (expression) blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676236/are-and-the-same-thing-as-embbed-code-expression-blocks)

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 2 application using .NET 4.0.
Just wanted to know, what is the difference between

```
 <%: item["Title"] %>
```

and

```
 <%= item["Title"] %>
```

?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676236/are-and-the-same-thing-as-embbed-code-expression-blocks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first will automatically HTML Encode the value. The second won't.

```
<%: item["Title"] %>
```

is equivalent to

```
<%= Html.Encode(item["Title"]) %>
```

Comment: And to avoid double encoding, `<%: %>` will _not_ HTML Encode types that implement `IHtmlString`.