# Could someone point me to the definition of <%:?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had this, and got "Howdy, "

```
<p> Howdy, <% Model.ToString(); %> </p>
```

I changed it to

```
<p> Howdy, <%: Model.ToString() %> </p>
```

and got "Howdy, Chris". (Which is what I expected.) I found several pages that listed the different kinds of inline expressions, but none of the ones that I found listed the one with the colon, and googling "<%:" doesn't seem to find anything ;).

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Comment: Also, <% %> is just going to evaluate the code inside the block.  If you want to display it on the screen, you need <%= or <%:

Answer (score 1):

```
<% string name = "<strong>basilard99</strong>"; %>
Welcome <% name; %>!
```

Renders `Welcome !`

```
Welcome <% Response.Write(name); %>!
Welcome <%= name %>! <!-- Same thing -->
```

Renders `Welcome <strong>basilard99</strong>!`

```
Welcome <% Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(name)); %>!
Welcome <%: name %> <!-- Same thing -->
```

Renders `Welcome &lt;strong&gt;basilard99&lt;/strong&gt;!`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx

And here too:
[Are <%: and <%= the same thing as embbed code (expression) blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676236/are-and-the-same-thing-as-embbed-code-expression-blocks)