# Difference between `<%: variable%>` and `<%= variable%>` in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are <%: and <%= the same thing as embbed code (expression) blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676236/are-and-the-same-thing-as-embbed-code-expression-blocks)

As clear from the heading I want to know the difference between `<%: variable%>` and `<%= variable%>` in ASP.NET.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676236/are-and-the-same-thing-as-embbed-code-expression-blocks or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517721/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-and?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

They do basically the same but `<%: variable%>` also html-encodes the output.

Comment: @lvan : and it's a MVC feature not WebForms , right ?

Comment: @mohsen.d, I believe so. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Comment: @mohsen.d it's also in WebForms but for the ASP.NET 4 and not the older versions of the framework